# Access from external to python development server

Tags: python, django

I can't access externally to python development server, I have a very small django project running on my machine, and now I want to enable computers in the same LAN have access to it, but it can't do.

There is no firewall running on my machine. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How are you running the server?
Have you tried something like this?

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

From [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/django-admin/):

> Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from other machines on your network. To make your development server viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0.

`0.0.0.0` means: bind to all IP addresses this computer supports. So, as [TheSingularity says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073977/access-from-external-to-python-development-server/4073994#4073994), you'll then be able to access your Django app by entering the private IP address usually beginning with 192.168.*; which is not accessible from the Internet.

Answer (score 6):

run your django app like this:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8800
```

you can access now your project from other machine like this:

```
http://<ip_address_machine_where_project>:8800
```