# Django web-server runs locally on windows server 2016 but is not available remotely

Tags: python, django, windows, server

Django web-server runs locally on windows server 2016 at http://127.0.0.1:8000 I have access to a web-page and all its functions, but when I try to access it remotely using http://193.124.64.241:8000 the page is not available. I've opened port 8000 in windows brandmauer settings for incoming and outcomming connections but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Look into the Django settings for ALLOWED_HOSTS. You may also have to run the server with "0.0.0.0". The address "127.0.0.1" is a loop back address, so that address should only be local.

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

Comment: Set it to ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['193.124.64.241', '127.0.0.1'] but it didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073977/access-from-external-to-python-development-server/4073993#4073993. Note that the development server should not be used on a public IP, it's insecure.